# java : upload files to HTTP server using POST, server code issue?

Tags: java, http, post, file-transfer

I am new to java and I have to transfer file from Android application to server. I took help from the link

[Uploading files to HTTP server using POST. Android SDK](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Its PHP code and works perfectly fine but I have to implement the server side code in Java not in PHP.

I googled and find the code from link [enter link description here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=62798)

```
InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine())!=null) {
        buf.append(line);
        }
        String s = buf.toString();
```

I am new to java so donot know how to write this code. I have NetBeans **netbeans-7.1.1-ml-javaee** installed.

Can somebody tell me that if this code is correct and how to put it in file or which type of file. I have created project but do not know how to put this code in file.

**Edits:**

Andriod code is working fine ... I want to develop Server code to get and save file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i hope this code can help u

```
try {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Image_url);
     MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
     File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
     ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");         
     mpEntity.addPart("photo", cbFile);
     mpEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(SmallyTaxiTabbar.unique_ID));
     mpEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody(SmallyTaxiTabbar.password));
     post.setEntity(mpEntity);
     HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post);
     HttpEntity resEntity = response1.getEntity();
     String Response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
     Log.d("PICTUREServer Response", Response);
     JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray("["+Response+"]");
     JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
     alert=(jsonobject.getString("alert"));
     client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    } 
     catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAGPost", e.toString());     
    }
```

where SmallyTaxiTabbar.unique_ID, password  is parameter value

**i Hope this code can help u ! **

Comment: Perfect, it works like charm!

**Note** Download httpcomponents-client-4.1-bin.zip from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and add httpclient-4.1.jar, httpcore-4.1.jar and httpmime-4.1.jar to your project.

Answer (score 1):

check if this library helps you. I have created wrappers for several http methods..

https://github.com/nareshsvs/android-libraries

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) library should help you process the content of the `POST` request in Java from a server point of view. It can be integrated with Servlets if required.

In particular, it will process the `multipart/form-data` content for you (which you would otherwise have to do manually if you were reading the request's `InputStream` directly line by line).